# lodash sorting an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, lodash

I have an array of objects response from the server, I am trying to sort by uid in ascending order, while keeping the entire array intact for the `data` array. Meaning in the `data` array there are 2 elements. I am trying to look at the uid in one of the arrays it is in of all the elements within the array and determine the order of how the elements should be placed within the `data` array.

I have tried the following using lodash, but it doesn't seem to work, but I feel I'm getting close and would like some assistance:

```
// sort by:
console.log(res.results[0].data[0].row[1].uid)

_.forEach(res.results, function(obj) {
  _.forEach(data, function(anotherObj) {
    _.forEach(row, function(row) {
      data.row = _.sortBy(data.row, function(row) {
      return row[1].uid;
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the array of objects returned from server:

```
var res = {
  results: [{
    columns: ['large', 'medium', 'small'],
    data: [{
      row: [{
        sid: 13,
        tid: 427
      },
        {
          uid: 69,
          vid: 450,
          wid: 65
        },
        null],
      multirow: {
        nodule: [{
          xid: '427',
          properties: {
            yid: 13,
            zid: 427
          }
        },
          {
            aid: '450',
            properties: {
              uid: 69,
              bid: 450,
              cid: 65
            }
          }]
      }
    },
      {
        row: [{
          sid: 13,
          tid: 427
        },
          {
            vid: 432,
            uid: 65,
            wid: 61
          },
          null],
        multirow: {
          nodule: [{
            xid: '427',
            properties: {
              yid: 13,
              zid: 427
            }
          },
            {
              aid: '432',
              properties: {
                bid: 432,
                uid: 65,
                cid: 61
              }
            }]
        }
      }]
  }],
  errors: []
};
```

Comment: Your `row` arrrays have 3 elements each, only 2 of them are objects, and only 1 of them has an `uid` property. What exactly do you want to sort, the `row` arrays, the `data` array(s) or the `results` array?

Comment: The variables in your code are totally unconnected. I guess you meant `obj.data` instead of `data`, `anotherObj.row` instead of `row`, and uh, that inner loop doesn't appear to make any sense at all…

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for pointing out my typo. I will fix the question. What I am trying to do is sort the elements within the data array by `uid`. And yes you are correct `uid` is in 2 places row and multirow. But I was just going to use row instead of multirow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that many loops:

```
_.forEach(res.results, function(result) {
  result.data = _.sortBy(result.data, function(datum) {
    return datum.row[1].uid;
  });
});
```

You only need to iterate over the results, each of which might have a data array that you are going to sort. The `sortBy` callback then takes each of the elements of that array and is supposed to return the value to compare.

Comment: Just tried what you proposed, in jsfiddle and it appeared to work.
yeah, I dunno why, I felt I needed more loops to get into that array. I guess lodash does more heavy lifting than I expected.

Comment: You've got three levels of arrays, yes, but: One you are iterating, one you are sorting, and one you are accessing directly with an index (I'm not even sure whether this should be an array at all).